# ImportError: cannot import name 'password_reset'

Tags: python, django, passwords

I am trying to do a password reset in django (2.1.1) but i keep getting the following error when i import password reset:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'password_reset'
```

Thsis is my import:

```
from django.contrib.auth import (
    authenticate,
    get_user_model,
    login,
    logout,
    password_reset,
    password_reset_done
)
```

Comment: The view has been removed in Django-2.1

Answer (score 15):

The `password_reset` view, etc. function-based views have been rewritten to class-based views: the [**`PasswordResetView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetView) class in [django-1.11](/questions/tagged/django-1.11), as is specified in the [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/1.11/#id2). These function-based views could still be used, but were *deprecated*.

As of [django-2.1](/questions/tagged/django-2.1), the function-based views have been removed, as specified in the [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/2.1/#features-removed-in-2-1).

You can write it like:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import PasswordResetView

from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path(
        'accounts/password_reset/',
        PasswordResetView.as_view(),
        name='password_reset'
    ),
]
```

of course you might want to change the URL, the view name, and pass parameters to the `as_view` to tailor the `PasswordResetView` to your specific use case.

Note that, as specified in the release notes, other related views have been removed as well, like **`password_change`**, **`password_change_done`**, **`password_reset_done`**, **`password_reset_confirm`**, and **`password_reset_complete`**.

Comment: Thanks Willem, now I am getting the following error: Reverse for 'password_reset_done' not found. 'password_reset_done' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Comment: @Mphoza: well like said in the last paragraph, you need to change *all* the views below to the CBV counterpart.